# Search API Index view shows all content pages, instead of just products commerce Kickstart

Tags: views, commerce

I'm using [Commerce Kickstart](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) and I have set up a search index using mysql rather than Apache Solr. Faceted search works perfectly. However if no facets are selected the results show all pages, including Terms of Use, 404 and shipping fees, to name but a few. I have tried setting up filters, but then it doesn't show any products. I'm attaching a screenshot of the results. I'm sure this is an easy fix, but I have spent hours testing and reading within the forums to try and find a solution, to no avail.
Many Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to filter results by content type? If yes, you can just set filter in tab "workflow" of your search index. It's "bundle filter". Good luck.